# Upgrading to Windows 10 fall creator fails

Tags: windows-10-v1703

This is the setuperr.log.

```
2018-01-23 16:43:24, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Suspend(1066): Result = 0xC1800104
2018-01-23 16:43:24, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(723): Result = 0x800705BB
2018-01-23 16:43:24, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(347): Result = 0x800705BB
2018-01-23 16:43:24, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::Execute(237): Result = 0x800705BB
2018-01-23 16:43:24, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(375): Result = 0x800705BB
2018-01-23 16:48:57, Error                 SP     CDownloadDUUpdates::DoExecuteInternal: Did not find hard disk space needed, when update cab files will not be extracted. This is unexpected! hr = 0x8000ffff
2018-01-23 16:48:58, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::DownloadDynamicUpdates: Failed to download updates. Error: 0x8000FFFF
2018-01-23 16:48:58, Error                 MOUPG  DUImage: Failed to execute GDR search and download [0x8000ffff]
2018-01-23 16:49:49, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::BuildSearchCriteria: Caller profile search criterion is not supported. hr = 0x80070032
2018-01-23 16:49:49, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Search: Failed to build the search criteria. hr = 0x80070032
2018-01-23 16:57:31, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::AssetUtils::GetProgramNameAndRegistryPathFromFile (811):   App should have registry path, swallowing error.[gle=0x8007139f]
2018-01-23 16:57:31, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::DataMigrationOutputter::PullAssetInfoOrDefaults (400):   Failed to get program name or arp registry path from application asset: [0x80004005].[gle=0x80004005]
2018-01-23 16:57:31, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::DataMigrationOutputter::DoOutput (169):   Failed to pull asset info for file: [0x80004005].[gle=0x80004005]
2018-01-23 17:24:55, Error                 SP     pSPRemoveUpgradeRegTree: failed to delete reg tree HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade[gle=0x00000005]
2018-01-23 17:25:13, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: "id" attribute is mandatory. void __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::LoadSupportedComponent(class UnBCL::XmlNode *,int,class Mig::CMXEMigrationXml *,class Mig::CMXEXmlComponent *)
2018-01-23 17:25:57, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #1980# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 32 (0x00000020) ): 3f003a005c007000610067006500660069006c0065002e007300790073000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2018-01-23 17:26:00, Error                 CSI    00000002 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #63789# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 32 (0x00000020) ): 3f003a005c007000610067006500660069006c0065002e007300790073000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2018-01-23 17:26:01, Error                 CSI    00000003 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #79727# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 12 (0x0000000c) ): 630061002d00450053000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2018-01-23 17:26:03, Error                 CSI    00000004 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #125560# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 32 (0x00000020) ): 3f003a005c007000610067006500660069006c0065002e007300790073000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2018-01-23 17:26:03, Error                 CSI    00000005 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #141498# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 12 (0x0000000c) ): 630061002d00450053000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2018-01-23 17:26:06, Error                 CSI    00000006 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #188221# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 32 (0x00000020) ): 3f003a005c007000610067006500660069006c0065002e007300790073000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2018-01-23 17:26:58, Error                 CSI    00000007 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #253945# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 32 (0x00000020) ): 3f003a005c007000610067006500660069006c0065002e007300790073000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2018-01-23 17:26:59, Error                 CSI    00000008 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #279587# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 12 (0x0000000c) ): 630061002d00450053000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2018-01-23 17:27:16, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2018-01-23 17:35:10, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] Failed to get homegroup members with hr=0x8007000D
2018-01-23 17:37:59, Error                        CSetupAutomation::Resurrect: File not found: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\automation.dat[gle=0x00000002]
2018-01-23 17:37:59, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectAutomation: Failed to resurrect automation: 0x80070002[gle=0x00000002]
2018-01-23 18:11:38, Error                 SP     [SetupCl library] Required profile hive does not exist: [\??\C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\NewOS\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\NTUSER.DAT].
2018-01-23 18:12:25, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2018-01-23 18:12:25, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{12bc829e-787e-48c2-a9b3-8d2e7aabf06e} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2018-01-23 18:22:12, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{52776FBF-403C-49cc-b7cb-dd557f36096A} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2018-01-23 18:22:19, Error                 MIG    DoApply_CallCreate: Unexpected exception: Could not create object HKU\S-1-5-19\Software\Microsoft\Peernet\Grouping. Exception FormatException: HKU\S-1-5-19\Software\Microsoft\Peernet\Grouping void __cdecl Mig::CRegistryDataStore::Create(class Mig::CDataUnit *)
2018-01-23 18:22:19, Error                 SP     Error READ, 0x000010DD while gathering/applying object: Registry, HKU\S-1-5-19\Software\Microsoft\Peernet\Grouping. Will return 0
2018-01-23 18:22:19, Error                 MIG    Error 4317 while applying object HKU\S-1-5-19\Software\Microsoft\Peernet\Grouping. Shell application requested abort
2018-01-23 18:22:19, Error      [0x08097b] MIG    Abandoning apply due to error for object: HKU\S-1-5-19\Software\Microsoft\Peernet\Grouping
2018-01-23 18:22:20, Error                        Apply failed. Last error: 0x00000000
2018-01-23 18:22:20, Error                 SP     pSPDoOnlineApply: Apply operation failed. Error: 0x0000002C
2018-01-23 18:22:21, Error                 SP     Apply (oobe boot apply, offline phase): Migration phase failed. Result: 44[gle=0x00000002]
2018-01-23 18:22:21, Error                 SP     Operation failed: Offline portion of first and oobe boot apply operations. Error: 0x8007042B[gle=0x000000b7]
2018-01-23 18:29:49, Error                 MOUPG  Finalize: Error reading narrator reg key: [0x80070002]
2018-01-23 19:31:54, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\ntprint.inf_x86_201ee9539cff1e59\ntprint.inf. Error: 0x80070002[gle=0x0000007a]
2018-01-23 19:50:53, Error                 SP     [SetupCl library] Required profile hive does not exist: [\??\C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\NewOS\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\NTUSER.DAT].
2018-01-23 19:51:41, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2018-01-23 19:51:41, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{12bc829e-787e-48c2-a9b3-8d2e7aabf06e} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2018-01-23 20:05:01, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{52776FBF-403C-49cc-b7cb-dd557f36096A} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
```

In theory I don't have any printer installed. But I dont' know how to check it for sure. Any suggestion of what to uninstall to make it work?

Comment: "In theory, I don't have any printer installed." - In order to work around this particular problem, download the current 1709 ISO from Microsoft, mount the ISO from within Windows, and launch the installer.

Comment: [Review in details the side effect of doing this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-update/error-code-0x80070002-or-0x80070003-windows/0d57dc7d-f629-4dac-a772-6162f075d6a9?auth=1).

Comment: I already installed from a usb. Tried several times. I would apreciate some help in this particular error...

Comment: I have read tons of generic links about hints. I am looking for something more specific like try uninstalling ths driver, look at this log file etc...

Comment: My suggestion didn’t mention trying to install from a bootable USB device.  Also linked you to instructions you might want to follow.  My suggestion on how to install the update, is just that a suggestion, if you come back and say it doesn’t work in have others.

Comment: Tried from the ISO. STill the same error.